# How to remove a range from start to end enclusive from a list

Tags: python, list

```
def remove_section(alist, start, end):
    """
    Return a copy of alist removing the section from start to end inclusive

    >>> inlist = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    >>> remove_section(inlist, 2, 5)
    [8, 7, 2, 1]
    >>> inlist == [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    True
    >>> inlist = ["bob","sue","jim","mary","tony"]
    >>> remove_section(inlist, 0,1)
    ['jim', 'mary', 'tony']
    >>> inlist == ["bob","sue","jim","mary","tony"]
    True
    """
```

I'm a bit stumped as to how to go about doing this any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def remove_section(alist, start, end):
    return alist[:start] + alist[end+1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
del alist[start:end+1]
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the list and delete the parts you don't want

```
newlist = alist[:]
del newlist[start:end]
```

Or you could combine two slices

```
newlist = alist[start:] + atlist[end+1:]
```

A quick timing of the two methods:

```
print timeit.repeat("b=range(100);a = b[:]; del a[2:8]")
print timeit.repeat("b=range(100);a = b[2:] + b[8:];")
```

Has the first method be about twice as fast as the second.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to copy the sequence then delete a slice.

```
>>> inlist = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
>>> outlist = inlist[:]
>>> del outlist[2:6]
>>> outlist
[8, 7, 2, 1]
```